# Separating 'body' of domain name from extension - DOS shell

Tags: string, batch-file

I tried everything possible, but still failed. I thought I got it at the point which I'll post
as my final attempt, but still isn't good [enough].

A script is being passed three arguments. Domain name, username and password.
But the probles is that I need domain separated in "domain" + ".com" format. Two variables.
I tried to split it using name.extension cheat, but it doesn't work quite well.

Check the simple code:

```
@echo off
echo.
set domain=%~n1
set ext=%~x1
echo %DOMAIN%
echo %EXT%
echo.
```

When you try it, you get:

```
D:\Scripts\test>test.bat domain.com

domain
.com

D:\Scripts\test>test.bat domain.co.uk

domain.co
.uk
```

First obviously does work, but only because I'm able to cheat my way through.
String operations in DOS Shell are a pain in the ass. I might be able to convince
a script writer to pass me 4 arguments instead of 3... but in case that fails... HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows ships with the Windows Scripting Host which lets you run javascript.

Change the batch file to:

```
@echo off
cscript //Nologo test.js %*
```

Create test.js:

```
if (WScript.Arguments.Length > 0) {
    var arg = WScript.Arguments.Item(0);
    var index = arg.indexOf('.');
    if (index != -1) {
        var domain = arg.substring(0, index);
        var ext = arg.substring(index);
        WScript.Echo(domain);
        WScript.Echo(ext);
    } else WScript.Echo("Error: Argument has no dots: " + arg);
} else WScript.Echo("Error: No argument given");
```

And you can use it:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Waqas\Desktop>test.bat domain.com
domain
.com

C:\Documents and Settings\Waqas\Desktop>test.bat domain.co.uk
domain
.co.uk
```

And that does what I think you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatize something (as stated in another answer), my solution would be to use appropriate tools. Install a Perl runtime or something else you're comfortable with. Or use the Windows power shell

Also, unless you supply your script with a list of valid top level domains, there is NO WAY, in no language, that your script can decide whether test.co.uk should be splitted as text and co.uk or test.co and uk. The only feasible possibility would be to make sure that you get only second-level-domains without sub-domain parts. Simply split at the first dot in that case.

BTW: I'm curious to why you would want to automate website creation in a Windows shell script. You aren't doing anything nasty, are you?